# Need a clever solution to dynamically produce an .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what I need to do -- *either*:

1. include an external file in my .htaccess file that resides on Server B, or
2. parse the .htaccess file on Server A using PHP, or
3. even a more clever solution (which I can't dream up at this time given my limited experience with httpd.conf and apache directives)

**Background**

I have an .htaccess file on Server A. I set its permissions to -rw-rw-rw (0666) and build it dynamically based on events throughout the day on Server B in order to achieve certain objectives of my app on Server A. I have since discovered that my hosting provider sweeps their server (Server A) each night and removes world writable files files and changes their permissions to 0664. Kudo's to them for securing the server. [Please no comments on my method for wanting to make my .htaccess file world writeable -- I truly understand the implications]

The .htacess file on Server A simply exists to provide Shibboleth authentication. I state this because the only aspect of the apache directives that is dynamic is the `Require user` stack.

Is it possible to include the "user stack" that resides on Server B in my .htaccess file that resides on Server A?

Or can I parse the .htaccess file on Server A via the PHP engine?

Thanks for helping my solve this problem.

Here's what the .htaccess looks like:

```
AuthType shibboleth
AuthName "Secure Login"
ShibRequireSession on
Header append Cache-Control "private"
Require user bob jill steve
```

All I want to do is update the `bob jill steve` list portion of the file each and every time I add/change/delete users in my application in an effort to make my Shibboleth required users (on Server A) synch with my MySQL/PHP web app (living on Server B).

Comment: The file doesn't need to be user-writable. Just make sure it is owned by the same user the apache server is running on. This can be done by having the php script create the file, instead of uploading it. For this to work you'll have to temparorily set the folder ,going to containing .htaccess, to be world-writable. But this only needs to be done once. This would be the least amount of since you already have the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks @Gerben. PHP runs as "nobody". My hosting provider will not allow me to change ownership permissions. (Been there many, many times before trying to get nobody to own it).

Comment: PHP runs as nobody, so if you let PHP create the file, like I said, the owner of the file will be "nobody".

Comment: Sorry @Geben. The document Root is not world writable - my hosting provider prevents that.

Comment: I forgot about that. Does the file need to be in the root?

Comment: @Gerben. It needs to exist to begin with ...it is an .htaccess file. So when I create it (via FTP) my user owner is not `nobody`. I simply need a solution to "update" an existing file that can;t be workd writeable. Hence I am trying to either do an include or parse via PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem a few days ago.

Given my HSP sweeps the server every night and changes any world writable file to 664 I thought about a different approach.

I did this:

1. during the day I made the directory containing my non-writable .htaccess file to 0777
2. then I deleted my .htaccess file
3. then I re-ran my script -- my fopen() command uses mode "w" (so I thought...if the file doesn't exist right now, why not let my php script create it brand new.)
4. because I said somewhere above here that my php runs as "nobody" -- voila!!!! I now had a file owned by nobody in the directory

Later that night my HSP swept the server and changed my directory from world writable -- but no big deal ... I got my .htaccess file owned by "nobody' and I can update the Require user directive automatically.

Thanks for everyone's help on this.

Answer (score 0):

(Version 2 of this post missed the `Require user` point on first reading -- sorry).

My immediate and my second instinct here is that dynamic `.htaccess` files (especially designed to be written from a separate web service) are a disaster waiting to happen in security terms and your hosting provider is right to do this, so you should regard this as a constraint.

However there is nothing to stop a process on server A within the application UID (or GID if mode 664) rewriting the `.htaccess` file.  Why not add a script to A which will service an "htaccess" update request.  This can accept the updated `Require user` dataset as  (JSON encapsulated, say) parameter, plus some form shared secret signature. This script can include any necessary validation and update the `htaccess` file locally.  Server B can then build the list and initiate this transfer via web request.

## Postcript following reply by Dr DOT

My first comment is that I am really surprised that your ISP runs your scripts as `nobody`.  I assume by this that all accounts are handled the same and therefore there is not UID / GID access control separation of files created by separate accounts -- a big no-no in a shared environment.  Typically in suEXEC /suPHP implementations any interactive scripts run in the UID of the scriptfile -- in your case, I assume your ftp account -- what you anonymise to `myftpuser`.  All I can assume is that your ISP is running shared accounts using mod_php5 with apache running as `nobody`, which is very unusual, IMHO.

However I run a general information wiki for a doctor which is also set up this way, and what I do is to have all of the application writeable contents in (in my case) directories owned by `www-data`.  There is surely nothing stopping you setting up such a directory with its own `.htaccess` file in it -- all owned by nobody and therefore updateable by a script.

If you want a simple example of this type of script see my article [Running remote commands on a Webfusion shared service](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-43).

Comment: Thanks @TerryE. I just don't know how to do that. (Tried for years with other app needs to update files via PHP in the manner I need here) My .htaccess file is owned by `myftpuser` and has group set to `samplegroup`. My PHP application runs as `nobody`. So how do I update a 664 file where I am not the owner nor in the group? Bear in mind I cannot change the owner, the group or the everybody octet in the permission set.

Comment: @Dr DOT, I've just added some supplementary info which I hope helps.  If you need more then I would really need to see your PHPinfo.  My email is on my profile.

Comment: `.htaccess` owned by nobody seems to have worked, though you've found a workaround to get this into root :-)  What I find worrying in this circumstance is that in reality `nobody` means "everybody" who is sharing the server with you has both read and write access to your data -- potentially without you knowing.  Don't you find this rather worrying?

Comment: `.htaccess` is inaccessible without first authenticating through Shibboleth (refer to my problem statements in the question post). So, "no" I am not worried.

Comment: No, I think that we're talking at cross purposes.  I am not worried about external users, I am worried about any other user / developer with an account with your hosting provider on the same box.  Any script that he or she runs will also run in nobody and therefore have full r/w access to your files including, say, any config,php which have your MySQL and equivalent credentials.

Comment: Got it, thanks @TerryE. This is a small private app with not many users. They are content writers and not developers. Yes, the risk is there but slight and one that I can afford given all the circumstances.